# how to use Sql join left with 2 tables but table2 has many-to-one relation

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I got 2 tables in my db and i want to join them together but because sometime i got more than one record in table 2 that connect to table1 i want to show them in a new column . i have app in .net C# that send the query and read from it.

**Table1:**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | James |
| 2 | Jane |
| 3 | Gil |

**Table2:**

| id | table1_id | countries_visited |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | USA |
| 2 | 1 | Germany |
| 3 | 2 | France |

and i want the end result from the query to be :

| id | name | country | country | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | James | USA | Germany | .... |
| 2 | Jane | France | no column here |  |
| 3 | Gil | no more columns |  |  |

my question is it possible to make rows have different columns?
and if its not possible than have all rows max country colums ( changed by the max amount of country visted to single key ) and have null in their value.

ex:

| id | name | country | country | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | James | USA | Germany | .... |
| 2 | Jane | France | null | .... |
| 3 | Gil | null | null | .... |

the .... represents if i had more countries to a single key.

maybe i got it all wrong but the reson i want this is because i can have some users with no countries visited and some with one or more without limiting .

Comment: How many columns do you need, what happens if someone has been to 100 countries?

Comment: if possible only the row with 100 countries will have all 100 colums . so every row have different number of country column based on how many country visited in table 2 to that id.  if not possible so all row will have 100 country column but all extra colum for each row will be with null. thanks for the comment

Comment: So what's your maximum possible number of columns? 100?

Comment: is it a problem if i dont want to limit it? again if it create colums based on the number of countries an id has i dont mind if its 2 , 4 or even 50. the reason the column size matter to me is because i intend to use in the app in the sqlcommand reader a loop with reader.fieldCount to know how many countries if any this row has and from there insert it into an object

Comment: It's much easier if you have a fixed number of columns. If there aren't that many for a given row, there will just be NULLs in those extra columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pivot on rownumber:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    MIN(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN countries_visited END) country1,
    MIN(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN countries_visited END) country2,
    MIN(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN countries_visited END) country3,
    ......... etc copy paste as many as you need
FROM (
    SELECT t1.*, t2.countries_visited,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t2.countries_visited) AS rn
    FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.table1_id = t1.id
) t
GROUP BY id, name;
```

You can also do this with the `PIVOT` keyword, but that is less flexible.

Comment: first of all thanks for the quick reply, i made mistake some where along the lines. i keep t1 and t2 and only change Table1 and Table2 to my real table names?

Comment: Ok i managed to get it to work but the result is not what i need i get : (id-name-country1-country2) \\ 1-James-Usa-null , 2-Jane-Germany-null , 3-Gil-France-null . but germany supposed to be james country 2 , france needs to be jane country1 and gil doesnt have any country - both null.               and my other question still stands - is there a way so when a colmun is null it wont even show so james will have both columns , Jane will have only country1 column and Gil will have only id and name colums and no country at all?

Comment: I don't understand, how do you expect to have a single table with differing columns on each row? That's just not how SQL works. If you don't want the word `NULL` showing, maybe change the pivot value to `MIN(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN countries_visited ELSE '' END)` then you get an empty string

Comment: thats what i wasnt sure about thanks for clarifying it. so i have two questions. 1. i used the code u wrote and it didnt work 100% . James didnt have both countries only USA and for some reson Jane got Germany (james 2nd country) and gil got france ( he dont have any country in table2) ,, 2.is it possible that the number of columns to create will be dynamic and will depend on the maximum number of countries any given ID got? ie - james got 2 countries so maximum columns of 2 , if in the futre *Gil* will have 3 rows because he visted 3 countries so now the new max will be 3

Comment: Sorry got the join condition wrong, have fixed

Comment: Thank you  again for the super fast replies !  two little things  1. how can i add table1 rows even if they dont have countries visited - ie Gil doesnt have a country visited but i still want him to appear on the table  just with all country columns null. 2. like i asked in the last comment is it possible to make the query dynamic? so that i check for the id with the most contries visited ( in this example its James with 2 ) and create 2 column acordingly?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN table2` instead of `JOIN table2` gets you everything from `table1`. Dynamic pivot: sure you can do that, there are hundreds of examples online. But it's difficult to debug, error-prone and prone to SQL injection, which is why I don't advise it if at all possible.